# itextsharp adding image to existing pdf

Tags: c#

i am trying to add an image using itextsharp but not having any luck
there are a ton of tutorials for adding an image to a new pdf doc but not and existing pdf so the .add menthod is not avaivlable

i am tring to do use the stamper write method to add image 
and i dont get any errors but no image shows up

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfIn); //get pdf

        if (File.Exists(pdfOut)) File.Delete(pdfOut); //reset 
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(pdfOut, FileMode.Create);

        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs);
        try
        {
            //  Convert base64string to bytes array
            Byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64decode);
            iTextSharp.text.Image sigimage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes);//
            sigimage.SetAbsolutePosition(10, 10);
            sigimage.ScaleToFit(140f, 120f);
            stamper.Writer.Add(sigimage);
        }catch (DocumentException dex){//log exception here
        }catch (IOException ioex){//log exception here
        }



        AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;
        //repeat for each pdf form fill field       
        fields.SetField("agencyName", name.Value);


        stamper.FormFlattening = true; // set to true to lock pdf from being editable
        stamper.Writer.CloseStream = true;
        stamper.Close();
        reader.Close();
        fs.Close();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you try the following adding it to bytes

```
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfIn)
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(pdfOut, FileMode.Create);
        var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs);
        var pdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
        iTextSharp.text.Image sigimage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes);
        sigimage.SetAbsolutePosition(100, 100);
        pdfContentByte.AddImage(sigimage);
```

Comment: Thanks you thank you thank you! that was the problem not using pdfContentByte

Comment: @Coldtold can you please explain,how to insert into new page?(via stamper). So take existing pdf and insert there an image in new page(specially for image)!? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

using following code you can able to add image to each page in an existing pdf file. ( I use this code for **desktop application**)

```
string FileLocation = @"C:\\test\\pdfFileName.pdf"; // file path of pdf file
var uri = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/projrct_name;component/View/Icons/funnelGreen.png"); // use image from project/application folder (this image will insert to pdf)
var resourceStream = Application.GetResourceStream(uri).Stream; 
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(FileLocation);
PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(FileLocation.Replace(".pdf", "(tempFile).pdf"), FileMode.Create));iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(resourceStream), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
img.SetAbsolutePosition(125, 350); // set the position in the document where you want the watermark to appear.
img.ScalePercent(35f);// not neccessory, use if you want to adjust image
img.ScaleToFit(140f, 100f); // not neccessory, use if you want to adjust image 
PdfContentByte waterMark;

for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++) // for loop will add image to each page. Based on the condition you can add image to single page also 
{
        waterMark = stamp.GetOverContent(page);
    waterMark.AddImage(img);
}

stamp.FormFlattening = true;
stamp.Close();// closing the pdfStamper, the order of closing must be important
pdfReader.Close();

File.Delete(FileLocation);
File.Move(FileLocation.Replace(".pdf", "(tempFile).pdf"), FileLocation);
```